# What is the purpose of putting an 'N' in front of function parameters in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the purpose of putting an 'N' in front of function parameters in TSQL?

For example, what does the `N` mean in front of the function parameter in the following code:

```
object_id(N'dbo.MyTable')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It indicates a "nationalized" a.k.a. unicode string constant.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239530

> When dealing with Unicode string constants in SQL Server you must precede all Unicode strings with a capital letter N, as documented in the SQL Server Books Online topic "Using Unicode Data".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276823%28SQL.80%29.aspx

> `nchar` and `nvarchar`
>
> Character data types that are either fixed-length (nchar) or variable-length (nvarchar) Unicode data and use the UNICODE UCS-2 character set.
>
> `nchar(n)`
>
> Fixed-length Unicode character data of n characters. n must be a value from 1 through 4,000. *Storage size is two times n bytes.* The SQL-92 synonyms for `nchar` are **national char and national character**.
>
> `nvarchar(n)`
>
> Variable-length Unicode character data of n characters. n must be a value from 1 through 4,000. *Storage size, in bytes, is two times the number of characters entered.* The data entered can be 0 characters in length. The SQL-92 synonyms for `nvarchar` are **national char varying and national character varying**.

Comment: That's interesting. I always wondered why 'N' stood for 'Unicode', and why they didn't just use 'U'

Comment: @JohnFx:  Just a guess, but I would bet that it was that 'U' has historically meant unsigned.

Comment: Nationalized text was in the SQL92 standard before unicode existed.