# SQL Server syntax question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.AWBuildVersion', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.AWBuildVersion;
GO
```

Whats the N symbolize in **N**'dbo.AWBuildVersion' & **N**'U'  ?

Comment: It's one of those pesky things that's really hard to Google or search on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of putting an 'N' in front of function parameters in TSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448203/what-is-the-purpose-of-putting-an-n-in-front-of-function-parameters-in-tsql).  There's another duplicate of this that came up days ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217535/n-prefix-before-string-in-transact-sql-query) has info on the subject. Basically the 'N' prefix denotes a Unicode string.

Answer (score 2):

It's for Unicode. It's like an nvarchar or nchar SQL data type.

For more information, see this: [You must precede all Unicode strings with a prefix N when you deal with Unicode string constants in SQL Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20150114081311/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/239530/en-us)

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with **Unicode** string constants in SQL Server you must precede all Unicode strings with a capital letter N.

The "N" prefix stands for National Language in the SQL-92 standard, and must be uppercase.

If you do not prefix a Unicode string constant with N, SQL Server will convert it to the non-Unicode code page of the current db before it uses the string.

Sometimes people use N' out of habit, not when it is really necessary.