# SQL: Whats the difference between ... WHERE O.type = N'U' ... and ... WHERE O.type = 'U' 

Tags: sql, where-clause

Today I came across an SQL statement that contains an element I've never seen. Maybe someone can elaborate? This SQL is from a stored procedure in Sybase ASE 15

> > SELECT O.id, OWNER = U.name, O.name, O.type FROM xxx.dbo.sysobjects O 
> >     LEFT JOIN xxx.dbo.sysusers U ON O.uid = U.uid 
> >     WHERE (O.type = N'U' OR O.type = N'S' OR O.type = N'V') ORDER BY O.name

Running

> > SELECT O.id, OWNER = U.name, O.name, O.type FROM xxx.dbo.sysobjects O 
> >     LEFT JOIN xxx.dbo.sysusers U ON O.uid = U.uid 
> >     WHERE (O.type = 'U' OR O.type = 'S' OR O.type = 'V') ORDER BY O.name

gives the same result as the SQL above.

What does the N infront of the parameter do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of putting an 'N' in front of function parameters in TSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448203/what-is-the-purpose-of-putting-an-n-in-front-of-function-parameters-in-tsql)

Comment: @OMG - You found it first. Searching for `N` isn't very easy!

Comment: Thanks, yeah its duplicate, sorry folks! I'm wondering how you find these questions? I couldn't think if a search to find the question, without knowing the answer

Comment: I knew the N stood for Nationalized - it's come up every couple of weeks on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The N ensures the value stated is treated as unicode

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's a "nationalized" (Unicode) string.

Answer (score 1):

The N stands for National - the N converts the VARCHAR to a NVARCHAR, which is used to store unicode data, which is used to store multilingual data in your database tables.