# How do I write a create table query that makes a unicode supporting table, in SMSS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode

I have SMSS   Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.3  `Select @@VERSION` shows `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64)`

Here are the queries, as you see from the image, the hebrew characters are not showing up in the table.

```
DROP TABLE ABCD
CREATE TABLE ABCD(AAA INT, BBB VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO ABCD(AAA,BBB) VALUES(1,'אאא')

select * from ABCD

select * from ABCD where BBB LIKE '%א%'
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NVARCHAR is is what you are looking for

I should add the **N** indicates a unicode string **[as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448203/what-is-the-purpose-of-putting-an-n-in-front-of-function-parameters-in-tsql)**

```
DROP TABLE ABCD
CREATE TABLE ABCD(AAA INT, BBB NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO ABCD(AAA,BBB) VALUES(1,N'אאא')

select * from ABCD

select * from ABCD where BBB LIKE N'%א%'
```

Returns

```
AAA BBB
1   אאא


AAA BBB
1   אאא
```